# execute a command by switching to root user in ansible

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, ansible, ansible-1.x

I am working on Ansible playbook to execute some of my tasks. In one of my tasks, I need to switch to particular directory and then execute a command using sudo but I need to do all these things by switching to root user first otherwise it won't work. So in general this is what I do without ansible:

```
david@machineA:/tmp/parallel-20140422$ sudo su
root@machineA:/tmp/parallel-20140422# sudo ./configure && make && make install
```

After above steps, I see GNU parallel library is installed in my system correctly. But with the below steps using Ansible, I don't see my GNU library getting installed at all.

```
- name: install gnu parallel
  command: chdir=/tmp/parallel-20140422 sudo ./configure && make && make install
```

Now my question is how can I switch to root user and execute a particular command. I am running Ansible 1.5.4 and looks like I cannot upgrade. I even tried with below but still it doesn't work:

```
- name: install gnu parallel
  command: chdir=/tmp/parallel-20140422 sudo ./configure && make && make install
  sudo: true
  sudo_user: root
```

I am running my playbook using below command:

```
ansible-playbook -e 'host_key_checking=False' setup.yml -u david --ask-pass --sudo -U root --ask-sudo-pass
```

Comment: I'm not sure about 1.5.4 but in Ansible 2.x you should use `shell` module instead of `command` when you want to execute arbitrary shell expression. And why do use `sudo` under `root` account, you already have maximum privileges?

Comment: yeah true on using sudo if I am already  switched to root. I can change that part to not use sudo anymore if I already have switch to root user.

Comment: I know command module is working fine bcoz I verified for other tasks and they work fine.. Somehow the issue for this task is I need to switch to root user and then only execute that command. And that I am not sure how can I do that using ansible.

Answer (score 4):

You need the [`become` directive](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html).

For example, to start a service as root:

```
- name: Ensure the httpd service is running
  service:
    name: httpd
    state: started
  become: true
```

you can also become another user, such as the apache user:

```
- name: Run a command as the apache user
  command: somecommand
  become: true
  become_user: apache
```

For your case, it will be:

```
- name: install gnu parallel
  command: chdir=/tmp/parallel-20140422 sudo ./configure && make && make install
  become: true
```

Comment: In ansible 1.5.4 there is no become I believe? right? and I cannot upgrade looks like

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> I know command module is working fine bcoz I verified for other tasks and they work fine.

`command` module might be working for other commands, but in this example you use a shell syntax (`&&`) to execute multiple commands. This syntax will not work in the `command` module (because this module runs commands directly from Python and does not support combined commands).

You need to use the `shell` module in this case.

```
- name: install gnu parallel 
  shell: ./configure && make && make install
  args:
    chdir=/tmp/parallel-20140422
  sudo: true
  sudo_user: root
```